# saveAs UNC path fails but mapped path works

Tags: vba, excel

I have some Excel VBA code below that saves an Excel file.  It works if I save using as a mapped drive, but fails if I use a UNC path.  I double-checked the UNC path and it is correct.

I get: "Run-time error '1004' method saveAs of object _Workbook failed"

```
mappedFileName = "x:\myFile.xlsm"
uncPathFileName = "\\fileServer01\pathPart\myFile1.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs mappedFileName, FileFormat:=52 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs uncPathFileName, FileFormat:=52
```

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=uncPathFileName, FileFormat:=52`   as in `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=x:\myFile.xlsm, FileFormat:=52`

Comment: Sorry, it would be as in `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\fileServer01\pathPart\myFile1.xlsm", FileFormat:=52`

Comment: Yes, per your suggestion, I tried that, but I get "application defined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad.  I upon triple checking I discovered the UNC path-part was misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Filename parameter `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=uncPathFileName, FileFormat:=52`

The drive may be mapped to a share... So you might no have the permissions through the UNC path...

If `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\fileServer01\pathPart\myFile1.xlsm", FileFormat:=52` then there may be an access issue.

The only other thing i can think of is trying the current format , FileFormat:=CurrentFormat